# Como funciona a verificação de maior e menor com string em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, comparação

Se executar a condição `'15000' > '100000'` o resultado será `true`

Se executar a condição `15000 > 100000` o resultado será `false`

Se executar a condição `'15000' > '200000'` o resultado será `false`

A dúvida aqui é entender o funcionamento do javascript na comparação de String e não saber qual o jeito certo de comparar.

Alguém sabe explicar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O JavaScript compara letra por letra, através do uso do dicionário de codificação que o JS usa (Unicode).

Logo, as strings não são comparadas num todo, mas são divididas e cada caractere é comparado individualmente, até que um seja maior ou menor que o outro.

Por exemplo:

```js
'A' > 'Z'
```

Retornaria `false`, tendo em vista que, no dicionário do Unicode, o código decimal das letras são:

```js
'A'.charCodeAt(0) // 65

'Z'.charCodeAt(0) // 90
```

Logo, `Z` é maior que `A`.

---

Desse modo, ao compararmos as strings `carro` `>` `cachorro`, temos `true`, já que a comparação é feita da seguinte forma:

1. `c` `>` `c` ⇒ `false`, logo, não é possível determinar qual caractere é maior.
2. `a` `>` `a` ⇒ `false`, logo, não é possível determinar qual caractere é maior.
3. `r` `>` `c` ⇒ `true`, o que **termina a comparação**, avaliando que `carro` é maior que `cachorro`.

É como se, por baixo dos panos, o JavaScript fizesse isso:

```js
const char1 = 'g'
const char2 = 'c'

console.log(
  char1 > char2
)

console.log(
  char1.charCodeAt(0) > char2.charCodeAt(0)
)
```

> Você pode conferir a tabela do Unicode [aqui](https://unicode-table.com/pt/).

---

A minha resposta foi imensamente baseada [nesta seção](https://javascript.info/comparison#string-comparison) da excelente documentação do site JavaScript.info.

Answer (score 5):

Quando existe a comparação `'15000' > '100000'`, imagine que alfabeticamente o valor **15**000 é maior que **10**0000.

Como se fosse uma lista de chamada da sala de aula em que os nomes são ordenados alfabeticamente, esta comparação a grosso modo seria desta forma.

```
1º '10000'
2º '19520000'
3º '2'
...
```

Dê acordo com a observação do *@fernandosavio* sobre a referência que fiz anteriormente, sugiro [este site](https://javascript.info/comparison#string-comparison) que possui uma explicação mais detalhada sobre a comparação de strings.

Comment: "A dúvida aqui é entender o funcionamento do javascript na comparação de String e não saber qual o jeito certo de comparar". Ele quer entender como funciona a comparação de cada tipo de dado no Javascript.

Comment: Removi a linha que digo a maneira correta de comparar. Mas a resposta que escrevi, lendo-a até o final, responde a dúvida do @felipema onde ele quer saber somente a comparação de números do tipo string. Obrigado pela observação :)

Comment: Cara o link do W3Schools não explica nada sobre comparação entre strings, apenas diz "compara alfabeticamente" e isso você já explica na sua resposta. Não sei se esse link precisa estar aí.. Sem contar que W3Schools não é uma boa referência.

Comment: @fernandosavio referência ruim é o MDN. Já vi traduções terríveis lá e informações desatualizadas aos montes. Pessoal fala mal da W3S mas eu nunca vi nada de errado lá rs. Tudo que pesquiso lá, as informações são ótimas. Mas, cada um é cada um :D

Comment: Bom saber que existe muitos lugares para obter conhecimento e se está oferecendo conhecimento, vale a pena citar :) Valeu galera

Comment: @Sam, referência ruim é a MDN? OK então. hahahah. Já existiu uma página chamada w3fools.com com vários grandes nomes de programação web apontando vários erros do W3Schools. Mas beleza..
Só vou botar um parênteses, eu sempre pesquiso as páginas em inglês pra evitar erros de tradução.

Comment: Pois é Vitor. Sobre o W3Schools, eu acho o seguinte (opinião minha): eu sempre pesquisei lá há muito tempo e sempre me atendeu bem (claro que algumas coisas eles não se aprofundam muito, mas aí vc procura outra fonte), até que um dia ouvi alguém falar que a W3Scools não era bom. Daí eu pensei comigo: "uai, pra mim parece bom"... então, eu acho que a w3Scools não é a 8ª maravilha do mundo, e se vc quer saber a fundo uma coisa, vc procura documentações oficiais etc, mas eu não fiquei achando que a W3S é ruim só por ouvi alguém falar. Bom, se alguém me provar que é ruim eu vou achar que é ruim rs

Comment: @fernandosavio pode ter erros, tudo bem, assim como eu já vi vários no MDN. Mas eu, particularmente, até hoje não me lembro de ter visto um erro na W3S. E olha que eu vejo muitas coisas quase todos os dias lá. E outra, tudo que vejo num lugar, eu procuro em outro para comparar, ou seja, tudo que vejo na W3S eu busco em outras fontes e até hoje não vi diferença rs :D (pelo menos não que eu me lembre).

Comment: Se você acessar o [W3Fools](https://www.w3fools.com/) ele explica que isso foi há bastante tempo... Não deve mais ser o caso mesmo, mas eu perdi a confiança e agora só sobrou essa birra.. hahahahaha